# How do I load my complete csv file into a table?

Tags: java, mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to upload a .csv file into a mysql table, but currently it will only upload 1001 lines of movies in the movies table when there is a couple more thousand lines that it leaves out

I tried changing the int to a Bigint to give it more room because the ints were only giving a max of 4 characters, the biggest was 7220 when it goes up to 6 or 7 charcters in the csv file
for example:

```
Lines included =

6116,Spice World,4.7,123
5902,A Bridge Too Far,6.9,207
Lines not included:
190955,Blood Ties,6,171
206647,Spectre,6.3,4466
13056,Punisher: War Zone,5.6,294

LAST line loaded:
7220,The Punisher,6.1,766 (LINE 1488)
last line not loaded:
7278,Meet the Spartans,3.7,359 (LINE 1608)
```

I notice it hits a point (7220) than doesnt bring in anything else higher but includes everything 7220 and below.

```
 statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Movies("
                    + "id BIGINT, "
                    + "title VARCHAR(100), "
                    + "vote_average VARCHAR(100), "
                    + "vote_count VARCHAR(100), "
                    + "PRIMARY KEY(id))" );

  String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + "movies.csv"
                    + "' INTO TABLE Movies FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'\n" +
                    "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'\n" +
                    "IGNORE 1 LINES";
            stmt.execute(loadQuery);//executing the query
```

UPDATE: REMEMBER TO SELECT "NO LIMIT" WITHIN MYSQL, that explains why select was only returning 1000 lines.

Comment: What is the last line loaded, and the first line not loaded? I suspect some formatting/parsing problem

Comment: There must be a typo in the separator, or the line break in line 7220, could you please post that part of csv?

Comment: Are you open to using any gui based tools to do the import?

Comment: @arcy added last and first

Comment: this content is not in order at all the id 7220 is not line 7220 @Chistos K.

Comment: @N0000B this code provided is what i use in java to import this csv

Comment: I wanted the FIRST line not loaded - it seems to me most likely that there is something about that line that causes a parser to error out, aborting the rest of the load. From your description, I gather it loads up until some line (meaning it parsed all of it correctly to that point), and then quits (indicating there is something it cannot handle about the next line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't run your code but,
Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE discounts(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The following  discounts.csv file contains the first line as column headings and other three lines of data.

[discount.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPm5P.png)

The following statement imports data from the  c:\tmp\discounts.csv file into the discounts table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The field of the file is terminated by a comma indicated by  Field terminated by '`,`' and enclosed by double quotation marks specified by enclosed by '`"`'.

Each line of the **csv** file is terminated by a newline character indicated by LINES TERMINATED BY '`\n`' .

Because the file has the first line that contains the column headings, which should not be imported into the table, therefore we ignore it by specifying  `IGNORE 1 ROWS` option.

Now, we can check the discounts table to see whether the data is imported.

```
SELECT * FROM discounts;
```

[table of discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUCEe.png)

Hope this was helpful.